# How do i save the state of my app? kivy/kivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

how can I save the app's every widget, list item added and changed by the user while using the app so that when he/she opens it it's still back to how he/she left it? I'm new to Kivy ,I would really appreciate help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the app is paused or closed (in the `on_pause` and `on_stop` methods of your App class), write code to save whatever app state you want. You will need to serialise it somehow, e.g. as json.

When the app is opened (in the `build` method of your App class), write code to read that file and reconstruct whatever gui state you wanted from it.

Comment: truly sorry, but could you give me some resources that are for kivy? some examples maybe? if that's okay? since i haven't really tried working with jsons yet. thank's a lot!

Comment: There probably aren't many resources specifically for this, because it's a straightforward combination of writing files (which is in the python documentation), and accessing information from Kivy (which is in the kivy documentation). If you can't work it out I suggest asking a specific question, ideally with a minimal example so people can show you what to change to achieve the result you're stuck on.